# I need multiple print result in one line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a problem with awk...
`awk -F "|" '{ print $1;split($5,a,".") ; print a[1] }' test > awk_test`
This command is right but the result is :

```
serveur1
7
serveur2
7
```

But I would like

```
serveur1 7 
serveur2 7
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the input data and just to fix the output formatting, you need:

```
awk -F "|" '{ split($5, a, "."); print $1, a[1] }' test > awk_test
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown attempts please try following.

```
awk -F "|" '{ sub(/\..*/,"",$5); print $1,$5 }' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making field separator as `|`, then substituting from DOT to everything to NULL in 5th field. Then printing 1st and 5th field. Basically why its giving in new line because you are using 2 times print statement here.